# SearchView seems not good(?)

Tags: android, searchview, android-appcompat

Note: I'm using AppCompat 21, ActionBarActivity.Not toolBar, I gave up. :(

It seems refreshing ActionView very fast.
If i expend SearchView, in the statusBar, the keyboard icon blinking very fest.

Here is the code.

main.xml(res/menu/)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="kr.ApiMaster3525.DICE.OffLine.ui.DrawerActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:theme="@style/MySearchViewStyle"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

DrawerActivity.java

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
    {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_controller).setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("SETTING_CONTROLLER", false));
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_statusbar_controller).setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("SETTING_STATUSBAR", false));
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_actionbar_controller).setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("SETTING_ACTIONBAR", false));
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_music_controller).setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("SETTING_MUSIC", true));
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```